# Right use of facebook access token?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Some context before I explain the problem. I am working on a project where:

1) User "Sam" logs in via facebook 
2) Creates an event 
3) Upload an album from facebook to this event 
4) Invites his friends "foo","bar" and "temp" to view this album 
5) Friends can accept invite and view these albums

So far so good. But the following is also part of the use case:
6) The user "foo" can also upload his facebook album to the event. So can "bar" and "temp". 
Point 6) is where the problem arises. Imagine the case where "foo" adds an album to an event. **Also "foo" is not friends with "bar" and "temp"**. Unless the album added by "foo" is not public, there is no way "bar" and "temp" can view this album with their access token. So here is what I am proposing and I want the experts on stackoverflow to comment on whether this is the right way or not.

**Solution 1**
When user uploads an album to an event in our app, save all the photo url's of that album to our database. This way all users of that event can see everyone's photos

**Solution 2**
Save user "foo"'s long lived access token to db. When user "bar" tries to see this album, use user "foo"'s access token to get the photos.

I am not sure about both solutions since I am afraid I might be violating facebook's privacy policy. Can I ask the user "foo" before he uses this app "Your photos will be viewed by everyone who is invited in this event" and only if he accepts it, we do either of the above solutions. Is that enough? I don't want to get sued :)

Sorry for the long question but I think it was necessary to explain the entire use case.

Comment: Upvoted because this is an excellently written question. For what it's worth, I would suggest checking Facebook's privacy policy and their developer documentation (I would imagine they'd have information there about a use case like your) or, as a last resort, contact Facebook.

Comment: @lunchmeat317. Unfortunately facebook's privacy policy is not that comprehensive. I guess I will need to contact Facebook if I don't find any answers here.

Comment: Why not just have users upload photos to the FB Event?  Or does "event" mean a non-FB event (not https://www.facebook.com/events/123456)?   Solution 2 is a no-no.  You cannot use User1's access token to allow User2 to view User1's data, even if you tell User1 ahead of time how you will use their permissions.  An access token allows your app (not other users of your app) to read a FB user's data.

Comment: @DonnLee thanks for the reply. I went through the FB data use policy https://www.facebook.com/full_data_use_policy. If you check the "Controlling what is shared when the people you share with use applications" read the music share example. Is the solution 2 still a no-no ?

Comment: @DonnLee and yes "Event" means a non FB event (our app specific).